# javascript/jquery get value of newly checked checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

the following is my code

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="brand.php?brand=bmw" name="bmw" <?php echo $checked; ?> > BMW</li>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="brand.php?brand=toyota" name="toyota"> Toyota</li>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="brand.php?brand=farari" name="farari" checked > Farari</li>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="brand.php?brand=nissan" name="nissan" checked > Nissan</li>
```

my javascript/jquery script is

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ckbox = $('#checkbox');
    var url = '';
    console.log(url);

    $('input').on('click', function() {

        if(ckbox.is(':checked')) {
            var url = $(':checked').val();
            console.log(url);
            window.location = url;
        }
    });
});
```

I want the page to go to the newly checked checkbox.How to make that happen?

Comment: multiple `id` with same `name` i have never tried this

Comment: FYI, ids shouldn't be duplicate `[id="checkbox"]`

Comment: The `id` global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document

Comment: What do you mean by "go to teh newly checked checkbox"?

Comment: Better you use class for get checkboxes at jquery and give unique ids to them.

Comment: lets say i m at brand.php?brand=bmw and bmw is checked  if we check nissan now then i want the url to be brand.php?brand=nissan

Comment: in php foreach the id will always be the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` should be a unique value in the whole document. Change your HTML to have unique id's for each checkbox and modify your jQuery selector based on class or input type.

Check below example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.chkbox').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      var url = $(this).val();
      console.log(url);

      window.location = url;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" class="chkbox" value="brand.php?brand=bmw" name="bmw"> BMW</li>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" class="chkbox" value="brand.php?brand=toyota" name="toyota"> Toyota</li>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" class="chkbox" value="brand.php?brand=farari" name="farari" checked> Farari</li>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4" class="chkbox" value="brand.php?brand=nissan" name="nissan" checked> Nissan</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var ckbox = $('.clscheckboxes');
        var url = '';

        $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
     var url = $(this).val();
                console.log(url);
                alert(url);
  } 
});
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" class="clscheckboxes" value="brand.php?brand=bmw" name="bmw" <?php echo $checked; ?> > BMW</li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" class="clscheckboxes" value="brand.php?brand=toyota" name="toyota"> Toyota</li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" class="clscheckboxes" value="brand.php?brand=farari" name="farari" checked > Farari</li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4" class="clscheckboxes" value="brand.php?brand=nissan" name="nissan" checked > Nissan</li>
```

Comment: `if(ckbox.is(':checked')) {` will return true even if one of the checkbox is checked. That shouldn't be the right way.

Comment: If you uncheck `Farari` it will still navigate to Farari page.

Answer (score 1):

One more sample code. Hope it'll work.

**JQuery Code**

```
$( ".checkbox" ).click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
        var page_url = $(this).val();
        window.location = page_url;
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="brand.php?brand=bmw" name="bmw"> BMW</li>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="brand.php?brand=toyota" name="toyota"> Toyota</li>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="brand.php?brand=farari" name="farari"> Farari</li>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="brand.php?brand=nissan" name="nissan"> Nissan</li>
```